# Displaying results based on customer first order after specific date SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

These are my current results

```
 CustomerID      OrderID    Date    TableFK
     1              1     2017-01-05    1
     1              2     2017-01-06    1
     1              3     2017-01-10    1
     2              4     2017-01-10    2
     2              5     2017-01-09    2
     2              6     2017-01-16    2
```

Now basically i want to return the customer who has placed his first order on or after '2017-01-09'

If i use

```
 WHERE Orders.Date > '2017-01-09'
```

I obviously get

```
 CustomerID      OrderID    Date    TableFK
     1              3     2017-01-10    1
     2              4     2017-01-10    2
     2              5     2017-01-09    2
     2              6     2017-01-16    2
```

But the output i am looking for is

```
 CustomerID      OrderID    Date    TableFK
     2              4     2017-01-10    2
     2              5     2017-01-09    2
     2              6     2017-01-16    2
```

How can i achieve this? i have an SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d55d/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `having` clause:

```
select o.TableFK as CustomerId
from Orders o
group by o.TableFK
having min(o.Date) >= '2017-01-09';
```

(The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d55d/4).)

Note that you do not need the `join` to `Customers` because the customers you want need to have an order.

A comment on naming.  The name `TableFK` is really meaningless.  It doesn't describe the column at all.  I'm a fan of having foreign keys have the same name as the primary key they are referring to, so `CustomerId` instead of `TableFK`.

Comment: Yeah i understand the naming conventions. It was just a quick example. This code works but it doesnt give me the exact ouput. What if i want to display the different orders and not group by? How can i get the same result?

Comment: @RyanGadsdon . . . I don't understand the question in your comment.  New questions should be asked as questions, in general, rather than in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner join and where clause to do this.

Using contents of your fiddle in the question:

```
select o.* from orders o
inner join (
              select tableFK, min(date) as firstOrder
              from orders
              group by tableFK ) f
              on f.tableFK = o.tableFK
              where f.firstOrder >= '17-01-09'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just run a check to see if the customer has a record in the orders table that is before your date, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Orders o
ON c.CustomerID = o.TableFK
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1
FROM Orders
WHERE Orders.TableFK = o.TableFK
AND Date < '2017-01-09')
```

This should work with the fiddle you created.